# How to add the changes made in home directory to my existing repository in github

Tags: git, github, repository

When I first started github I added my files from my computer in github in the following way:

```
    -git init
    -git remote add origin https://github.com/[username]/[reponame].git
    -git remote set-url origin https://[username]@github.com/[username]/[reponame].git
    -git push -u origin master
```

In the folder I am currently working in my computer I made some changes, added and erased some files.

Now I want to update my repository in github with the changes I did. Well I tried a bit but nothing changed. What commands should I follow? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following command,
The fist command will add all the files queue
The second command will save the changes
The third command will push the changes into repository

git add *

git commit

git push

Answer (score 1):

Once you have made your changes, you just need to push to your repository in github.

**git push origin master**

Let's say I want to add a document.

**touch text.txt**

**git add text.txt**

**git commit -m "adding text.txt"**

**git push origin master**

It will ask you for your username and password in github.